# How to find CLSID from CoCreateInstance in IDA?

Tags: ida, disassembly

I've find a `CoCreateInstance()` in IDA disassembly (after `CoInitializeEx()`). Here are the assembly:

```
loc_18000499D:          ; pUnkOuter
xor     edx, edx
mov     [rsp+68h+ppv], rbx ; ppv
lea     r9, riid        ; riid
lea     rcx, rclsid     ; rclsid
lea     r8d, [rdx+4]    ; dwClsContext
call    cs:CoCreateInstance
mov     ebx, eax
mov     eax, 8007019Eh
cmp     ebx, 80040154h
cmovz   ebx, eax
test    ebx, ebx
jns     short loc_1800049D7
```

And the pseudocode is:

```
CoCreateInstance(&rclsid, 0i64, 4u, &riid, v4 + 1);
```

When I click the `rclsid` it is redirected to read-only data segment. Here is the .rdata section:

```
.rdata:0000000180007930 ; IID rclsid
.rdata:0000000180007930 rclsid          dd 4F476546h            ; Data1
.rdata:0000000180007930                                         ; DATA XREF: f_CoInitialize+A7↑o
.rdata:0000000180007930                 dw 0B412h               ; Data2
.rdata:0000000180007930                 dw 4579h                ; Data3
.rdata:0000000180007930                 db 0B6h, 4Ch, 12h, 3Dh, 0F3h, 31h, 0E3h, 0D6h; Data4
.rdata:0000000180007940 ; IID riid
.rdata:0000000180007940 riid            dd 536A6BCFh            ; Data1
.rdata:0000000180007940                                         ; DATA XREF: f_CoInitialize+A0↑o
.rdata:0000000180007940                 dw 0FE04h               ; Data2
.rdata:0000000180007940                 dw 41D9h                ; Data3
.rdata:0000000180007940                 db 0B9h, 78h, 0DCh, 0ACh, 2 dup(0A9h), 0B5h, 0B9h; Data4
```

So, How can I find the CLSID? I tried to change the data type with `D` key but can't understand it.

Comment: clsid is guid  which is a structure either create the struct and apply it or create a 16 bytel long array with numpad * button

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CLSID is a GUID and although a GUID can be represented as a string, it's really a struct that looks like this:

```
typedef struct _GUID {
  DWORD Data1;
  WORD  Data2;
  WORD  Data3;
  BYTE  Data4[8];
} GUID;
```

Although there is no way to display the GUID as a string in Ida you can convert it to a struct like this:

Select the 16 bytes that represent your CLSID, right click and select Structure from the Popup Menu. Then from the Sub menu select `_GUID`:
[image: Structure Menu]

This is the result showing the Data1, Data2, Data3 and Data4 members
[image: Bytes converted to GUID struct]

If you want to convert it to string you would need to create an idc script that does something like this: `sprintf(szGuid, "{%08X-%04X-%04X-%02X%02X-%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X}", guid.Data1, guid.Data2, guid.Data3, guid.Data4[0], guid.Data4[1], guid.Data4[2], guid.Data4[3], guid.Data4[4], guid.Data4[5], guid.Data4[6], guid.Data4[7]);`

Comment: An IID is a globally unique identifier (GUID) value, so they are the same.

Answer (score 2):

From @Remko's idea, I made a IDC script to convert the GUID data to a sting. Here is the script:

```
#include <idc.idc>

static MakeGuid(ea)
{
    auto string = sprintf("{%08X-%04X-%04X-%02X%02X-%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X}\n", 
        Dword(ea), Word(ea+4), Word(ea+6), Byte(ea+8), Byte(ea+9),
        Byte(ea+10), Byte(ea+11), Byte(ea+12), Byte(ea+13), Byte(ea+14), Byte(ea+15)
    Message(string);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Instructions:

Make a text file in any text editor. Add .IDC extension. Paste the above code. Load the IDC script file in IDA with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> (or File > Load Script menu). Open the output window with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> (zero). Type `MakeGuid(variable_name);` below of that window and the GUID will be shown as string. For example, as in my question, type `MakeGuid(rclsid);`. Always put a semicolon after the function.

#### Sources:

- [useful IDA idc scripts: formatdata.idc](http://nah6.com/~itsme/cvs-xdadevtools/ida/idcscripts/formatdata.idc)
- [GitHub: IDA-IDC-Scripts/formatdata.idc](https://github.com/nihilus/IDA-IDC-Scripts/blob/master/Willem_Jan_Hengeveld/formatdata.idc)